# Find uncommon characters between two strings

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have following code:

```
public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string word1 = "AN";
    string word2 = "ANN";

    //First try:
    var intersect = word1.Intersect(word2); 
    var unCommon1 = word1.Except(intersect).Union(word2.Except(intersect));

    //Second try:
    var unCommon = word1.Except(word2).Union(word2.Except(word1));              
  }
```

Result I am trying to get is `N`. I tried few ways to get it by reading online posts, I am unable to figure it out. Is there a way to get uncommon character between two strings using linq.

Order of characters in string does not matter. 
Here are few more scenarios: 
FOO & BAR will result in F,O,O,B,A,R. 
ANN & NAN will result in empty string.

Comment: What _are_ the results for this code? And what would be the result for "FOO" and "BAR"? And for "ANN" and "NAN"?

Comment: @CodeCaster Above code gives empty string. FOO & BAR will result in F,O,O,B,A,R. ANN & NAN will result in empty string.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include those additional details. So order doesn't matter?

Comment: @CodeCaster No order should not matter

Comment: @CodeCaster - Updated question.

Comment: "Uncommon" is the wrong English word for this. "Uncommon" means unusual. I think you need a whole phrase such as "do not have ... in common".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straight forward LINQ function.

```
string word1 = "AN";
string word2 = "ANN";

//get all the characters in both strings
var group = string.Concat(word1, word2)

    //remove duplicates
    .Distinct()

    //count the times each character appears in word1 and word2, find the
    //difference, and repeat the character difference times
    .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Repeat(i, Math.Abs(
        word1.Count(j => j == i) - 
        word2.Count(j => j == i))));
```